# Server Derby db remote to client Java

Tags: java, database-connection, derby, javadb

I can't get a clear picture on the db connection.

We have a server in Linux. It has a DerbyDB too.  I can have a db in it.
I have to create a program that runs on more than one client computers (windows).

The client programs will perform add-delete-update operations on records in remote db over LAN.

How can I connect to remote db? (they would not allow any server side program so sockets may not work out here).

***I have to give Server IP manually before login(if the server IP change) The Login to log-out should have a db connection.***

I am using Java Swing (NetBeans)

I want to test the connection is by giving the IP, and run a simple SELECT on db.

I am afraid about the IP, Port issues.
**I just need to communicate to db other than manual IP assign in code.**

Can anyone help?

Comment: I am quite rusty in my Java Swing skills now, but I feel you can get this done by using normal JDBC connection methods. And if your server is in a good condition, the IPs won't change that frequently

Comment: @SheikhAman i prefer a conf/txt file where the host,username,password is editable. And the program always read from it. It makes the program distributable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/).

You need to provide the host,port,username,password and it should work.

The steps you need to do are:

1. [Download](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html) the derby JDBC driver
2. Add it to your class path
3. [Use the correct url to connect](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html)